# Splitting String by column with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

```
4 
1 1
1 2 1
0
1 1
```

This is a String I get as input, but I just need every column, starting with the second column, aka:

- 1 (second row)
- 2 and 1 (third row)
- 1 (fifth row)

This `String` has no fixed size in how many lines there could be or how many columns (columns being split by one space).

I think this is fairly easy by using:

```
string.split("enter regex here");
```

I need every column after the first.
I'm still learning with regex but I just can't seem to find a good solution.
I know about `"\\r?\\n" and " "` for splitting but don't know how to connect both to get every column.
Any help is very appreciated :)

Another String could look like this:

```
2
1
1 2
9 3 5
1 3
0 9 2 4
0
```

In that case, I would need `2, 3, 5, 3, 9, 2, 4`.

Comment: How many digits long can each individual number be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First trim leading column, then split on white space:

```
String[] split = str.replaceAll("(?m)^\\d+\\s*", "").split("\\s");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/rAz4cu).

The replace uses the *multiline flag* `(?m)`, which makes `^` match the start of *every line*, and `\s` matches spaces, so the first column is effectively deleted from every line, but `\s` *also* matches newlines, so lines with only one column are deleted entirely. Although the new lines are retained in lines with more than 1 column.

Because `\s` matches space *and* newline, the split splits between columns and between (first column removed) lines, yielding the desired result.

I believe this is the least code required for a solution.

Comment: Yes, this is it, thanks for the detailed explanation, helps me to learn and get better at it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=\d )\d+
```

It matches any combination of digits, followed by "digit + space".

Instead of splitting on this, you should use the matcher with this regex.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/bRiKNm/1).

Comment: I'm curious, what does the `<=` do?

Comment: It checks whether what comes before the match (outside parenthesis) follows that pattern `\d `. If you want to check the negation of it, you do `<!` @ValerijDobler

Comment: After playing around with your example I think I grasped it. It requires that the first group has to match but is ignored in the matching. "Positive Lookbehind" is the therm.

Comment: This is exactly what I searched for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can split each line using `String.lines` to get a stream of the lines and then flatmap those lines after spliting at each space using `Pattern.splitAsStream` and skip the first column and join back together using comma as a delimeter:

```
String input ="4 \n"
            + "1 1\n"
            + "1 2 1\n"
            + "0\n"
            + "1 1\n";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
String result   = input.lines()
                       .flatMap(line -> pattern.splitAsStream(line).skip(1))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(result);

//1, 2, 1, 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it natively, ae without importing utils? like pattern and collectors?

Comment: @Loewe8 yes: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72593609) does it without any imports.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "4 \n"
        + "1 1\n"
        + "1 2 1\n"
        + "0\n"
        + "1 1\n";
String result = s.replaceAll("((^|\\n)\\d|[ ])", "").replaceAll("(\\d)(?=\\d)", "$1, ");
System.out.println(result); 
//1, 2, 1, 1
```